# 3 dynamic inline divs not staying in place

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a simple 3 div layout. The div's width's are each set to `33.3%` and height is set to `100%`. What I'd like to have happen is on hover over any of the div's, that div expands to `40%` width while the other two each take a `3.5%` decrease in their respective widths. Unfortunately, what's happening is the div on the right drops to the next line.

I'm pretty confident I could do this easily with jQuery, but i'd prefer if I could do this with pure css.

Here's the fiddle for the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/99gL47rp/1/

any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: You have to use jquery for easy solution.

Comment: Like I said, I'd really prefer to try it with pure css, if it can't be done i'll just have to go that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can totally do this! You just have to think about it a little bit differently. https://jsfiddle.net/jpw4w7ou/.

```
/*Use this to give all the child divs the same 33% width */
#sections > div {
    width: 33.3%;
}

/*On hover of the container, drop ALL the children's width to 30% */
#sections:hover > div {
    width: 30%;
    transition:width 0.5s;
}

/*Finally, give the actual child div you are hovering over a width of 40%. This will override the previous selector's 30% width only for the currently hovered element */
#sections > div:hover{
    width: 40%;
    transition:width 0.5s;
}
```

Note that I removed `clear:left`, it wasn't necessary and was causing issues.

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME! That's exactly what I was looking for! Something was telling me this was possible. I didn't even think about the child selector. Thanks! :D

Comment: No problem... this was a fun one :)

Answer (score 1):

Usinng CSS Flex method you can achieve this very easily, you only need to use `%` value and have to use `word-wrap: break-word;` to break the long text into next line. Check [Demo](http://jsbin.com/tiyaleqaro/1/edit?html,css,output).

```css
.flex
   {
      /* basic styling */
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      border: 1px solid #555;
      font: 14px Arial;

      /* flexbox setup */
      display: -webkit-flex;
      -webkit-flex-direction: row;

      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
   }

   .flex > div
   {    -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
-webkit-transform-origin:0 100%;
transform-origin:  0 100% ;
      -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
      flex: 1 1 auto;
word-wrap: break-word;
      width: 30%;
      -webkit-transition: width 0.7s ease-out;
      transition: width 0.7s ease-out;
   }

   /* colors */
   .flex > div:nth-child(1){ background : #009246; }
   .flex > div:nth-child(2){ background : #F1F2F1; }
   .flex > div:nth-child(3){ background : #CE2B37; }

   .flex > div:hover
   {
        width: 40%;
   }
```

```html
  <div class="flex">
    <div>portttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</div>
    <div>pricinggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg</div>
    <div>portttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i do not think so that it can by don by css only. You need to use jquery like

```
$( "#pricing" ).hover(
  function() {
    $('#portfolio').css('width','30%');
    $('#contact').css('width','30%');
  }, function() {
    $('#portfolio').css('width','33.3%');
    $('#contact').css('width','33.3%');
  }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mike_manish/99gL47rp/7/

Comment: If jQuery really is my only option for this, that's fine as I'm quite familiar with jQuery. However, the problem with your example is that, it out puts the exact same problem my code did - the right div still drops to the next line and when the mid or right div are hovered on, they're glitchy because of the line change.

Answer (score 0):

We can not target another id or class on mouse hover event of another id or class.

Comment: True, but that doesn't mean it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following way:

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: "verdana", sans-serif;
}
#nav-bar{
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 top: 0;
 background-color: #000000;
 opacity: 0.5;
 position: fixed;
}
#sections{
 margin-top: 70px;
}
#pricing{
 width: 33.3%;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 background-color: #ff0000;
}
#pricing:hover {
 clear: left;
    width: 40%;
 transition:width 0.5s;
}
#pricing:hover ~ #portfolio {
    width: 30%;
 transition:width 0.5s;
}
#pricing:hover ~ #contact {
    width: 30%;
 transition:width 0.5s;
}
#portfolio{
 width: 33.3%;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 background-color: #00ff00;
}
#portfolio:hover {
 clear: left;
    width: 40%;
 transition:width 0.5s;
}
#contact{
 width: 33.3%;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 background-color: #0000ff;
}
#contact:hover {
 clear: left;
    width: 40%;
 transition:width 0.5s;
```

```html
<div id="nav-bar">
</div>
<div id="sections">
<div id="pricing">
pricinggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
</div>

<div id="portfolio">
portttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
</div>

<div id="contact">
contacttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
</div>
</div>
```